# Check for duplicates across two columns sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently designing a mysql database that contains emails, and I am trying to find the best way to store said emails. I have read in articles and some stackoverlow posts that it is a good idea to store the local part of an email address separately to the domain, as many emails use the same domain (e.g. gmail.com). Currently I have set up a table that is named emails that contains an id, local_email, and domain_id, the domain_id being a foreign key for a table containing email domains. According to what I found this is the best way to set up a database as it minimises the storage used in repeating email domains.

So far this seems to work very well, however the one problem I seem to be having is that when I want to add a new email, what is the best way to ensure that a duplicate is not being added. Normally I would use the UNIQUE constraint, but since the local part and domain of the email are split up into two different columns, I am unable to do that. So my question is, is there a way to check if an exact email already exists on the database side or do I have to do that at an application level, and if I do, will I not have a problem with the race condition (I know that this is unlikely but would still prefer to not introduce bugs lik that).

I am fairly new to database design so any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: You can use a UNIQUE constraint with multiple columns. Just separate them with commas. Example: `CONSTRAINT uq1 UNIQUE (local, domain)`.

Comment: In most DBMS systems, data processing speed takes precedence over disk size. I doubt that your "normalization" is reasonable.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thank you, I did not know that. What does the uq1 mean?

Comment: @Akina, That is a good point, I hadn't thought of the speed lost, I wonder why those articles recommended that then.

Comment: @bdb8 It's just a name for the constraint. When databases go to production, it's a good idea to name the constraints, so you can reference them later, if you need to change them or to delete them.

Comment: *why those articles recommended that then* Read these articles and evaluate to what extent the justifications given there make sense. If the compactness and misprintless are the only reasons then I'd prefer to consider them insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The Impaler gave you a really good idea by using `CONSTRAINT uq1 UNIQUE (local, domain)` . Apart from that, we can also use a trigger to check for duplicate values, which provides you with customizations such as returning an error message of your choice . Assuming we have four entries in the `domains` table using `insert into domains (domain_id,domain_name) values(1,'gmail.com'),(2,'yahoo.com'),(3,'yahoo.co.nz'),(4,'msn.com');`  and the `emails` table is empty at the moment. Then we create a trigger which checks for the uniqueness of new rows before they are inserted. If the uniqueness is violated, an error with a message is signaled.

```
delimiter //
drop trigger if exists check_duplicate ;
create trigger check_duplicate before insert on emails for each row 
begin
if new.local_email in (select local_email from emails where domain_id=new.domain_id) then
signal SQLSTATE VALUE '99999' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'duplicate address detected';
end if;
end//

delimiter ;
```

After creating the trigger, we move on to test against it using the following INSERT statements:

```
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('john',2); -- successful
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('marry',1); -- successful
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('jack_frost',2); -- successful
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('jack_frost',1); -- successful
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('jack_frost',2); -- error message 'duplicate address detected'
insert into emails (local_email,domain_id) values ('jack_frost',3); -- successful
```